# mysql_query command makes entire page not load?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set an EC2 webserver on AWS with Apache, PHP, MYSQL and every code has worked so far in it (PHP and HTML5) except this one. I'm new into PHP and mySQL so the answer may be really simple.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Couldn't Connect") ;

echo 'Connected!';

        mysql_select_db('testdatabase') or die("Couldn't find database");

echo "Connected!";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt'>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">

Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/><br>
Telefone <input type="text" name="telefone" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br>

</form>


<?php

        $nome =  $_POST['nome'];
        $telefone =  $_POST['telefone'];

        if(empty($nome) || empty($telefone)) {
                echo "Preencha tudo!";
        }       else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO dados(nome,telefone) VALUES ('$nome','$telefone')";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        if($result == false) {
                        die("Error".mysql_error());
                        }


                }


?>


</body>
</html>
```

As you might have guessed, this is an example code that worked in a tutorial I watched. Funny thing is, I get no error whatsoever.

The page simply shows nothing and keeps loading forever. After a lot of struggle, I found that if I simply deleted the

> $sql = "INSERT INTO dados(nome,telefone) VALUES
>   ('$nome','$telefone')";

line, the page would display the form and echo commands, but obviously the php wouldn't work properly.

The database I'm using in mysql is:

```
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_testdatabase  |
+-------------------------+
| dados                   |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from dados;
+----+-------+------------+
| id | nome  | telefone   |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 | Peter | 2147483647 |
+----+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have no idea what it could be. I've already tried writing a brand new code with the same purpose and got the same result: blank page ever loading.

I don't know if it has any correlation, but the language I used in the code is portuguese.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an extra } after that else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your code on an EC2 instance freshly installed and it works as expected.

[image]

```
mysql> create table dados(nome varchar(50), telefone varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| dados          |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from dados;
+------+----------+
| nome | telefone |
+------+----------+
| test | 111      |
+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If you are receiving a blank page when connecting to your page, it might be related to EC2 Security Group configuration.

Security Groups allow you to define what kind of network traffic is authorised to flow to or from your instance.  Incoming traffic is denied by default.

If you deploy a web server, you must explicitly authorise traffic to port TCP 80.

[image]

You can learn more about EC2 Security Groups here :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: I checked the Security Gropus and everything seems OK. I set the authorizations for HTTP, HTTPS and SSH as in this [image](http://i.imgur.com/zh4mFRX.png). Looks pretty much the same as yours to me.

Comment: OK, good check. Two others checks : 1/ I would connect to yoru EC2 instance and check the Apache logs in /var/log/httpd.  Their should be an access.log and error.log file.  Is there any error message in there ? 2/ from the EC2 instance can you connect to your page ? You can test this using the command 'curl http://your_public_ip_address/you_path_to_your_page.php'

Comment: Thanks for the time. Nothing in access.log and a [small error message](http://i.imgur.com/1t97L8r.png) in error.log that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem. As for the curl command, I get no info nor errors back, so I'll assume it worked?

Comment: So weird. Now the page isn't blank anymore, but still seems to be loading forever. I don't remember changing anything significant. Code works as intended though, that's what really matters. If you could still help with the loading, I'll be very grateful. If it is of any help, the DNS I'm using right now is http://ec2-54-94-211-146.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/teste.php

Comment: Your URL is loading fine on my browser (Chrome on Mac OSX) - I also tried Safari and Firefox ... they all behave correctly.  No problem

Comment: curl works too : 10ddb1cbf490:~ stormacq$ curl http://ec2-54-94-211-146.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/teste.php
Connected!Connected!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt'>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">

Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/><br>
Telefone <input type="text" name="telefone" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br>

</form>


Preencha tudo!

</body>
</html>